# How to draw all x-axis labels in a BarChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using the great mpandroidchart libs for drawing various graph in our apps and first of all I'm deeply sorry if this question will be redundat or stupid. 
Anyway, I have this BarChart which is drawing great except to the fact that i can't find a way to force the drawing of ALL XLabels. It just draw some of them and obviously if I pinch the view they are coming up but i would like to show them always, without the needs of zooming.
Hope is much clear. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately **there is no way to force draw all x-axis-labels**. The chart will prevent overlapping labels from being drawn.

What you can do is reduce the space between the labels to the absolute minimum by calling:

```
XAxis xa = chart.getXAxis();
xa.setSpaceBetweenLabels(0); // space in characters
```

This will make sure the space between the labels is kept to a minimum. Default space between labels is 4 characters.

Comment: I already tried with a space of 2 but not with 0. I'll give it a chance as soon as I can.

Comment: The solution you suggested work in my case. thank you. I would upvote your answer but i don't have enough reputation, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is a bit older... But the posted solution didn't work for me.
I used:

```
XAxis xa = chart.getXAxis();
xa.setLabelsToSkip(0);
```

And this worked perfectly! Hope it helps somebody ;)

Comment: You could be right. The question was referring a pre-2.0 version of the lib and i know that after 2.0 it's changed a lot of things so, maybe the correrct answer it's now yours.